# Set IME caret position in a c# control

Tags: c#, ime

I have made a text editor control in C#, where I have inherited from `Control`.

Some of my users use an IME (Input Method Editor) for input, so I would like to add more support for it.

Normally, an IME will pop up where the caret is, but I can't figure out how to tell it where to show up. I assume there is some standard way of doing this, since there are some IME fields in the `Control` class.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution. The code here did it for me.
http://www.koders.com/csharp/fidEB8980C0605213D81D1D8364B00F09538F1DF83D.aspx